# Como guardar as Strings de uma leitura de arquivo?

Tags: java, eclipse

Pessoal estou fazendo a leitura de um arquivo.txt e gostaria de salvar todas as Strings como eu poderia guarda isso tudo ?
Abaixo segue o meu código de escrita que estou utilizando , no caso eu gostaria de guarda a String linha .

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
              try {
                  File f = new File ("c:/teste.txt");
                  InputStream is = new FileInputStream("c:/teste.txt");
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    String linha = reader.readLine();


                    while (linha != null) {



                        System.out.println(linha);

                        linha = reader.readLine();

                        }
                        reader.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
List<String> linhas = Files.readAllLines("c:/teste.txt")
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/ReadText.java).

Muito mais fácil, né?

[Documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path)).